# WCF Service works with a client on the same machine, but not if I move the client to another machine on the same network

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint

I have a WCF service running on my machine. This service has the following configuration in the app.config file under system.servicemodel:

```xml
<client />
<services>
  <service name="AnchorWcfService.AnchorService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="AnchorService" contract="AnchorWcfService.IAnchorService" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransportSecurity" />
    <endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" /> 
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="TransportSecurity" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5000000" maxDepth="128" maxArrayLength="5000000" />
      <security mode="None">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

From my code, I start the host like this:

```
serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof (AnchorService), new Uri("http://192.168.0.16:8080/"));
serviceHost.Open();
```

The IP address of the local machine is of course 192.168.0.16.

In addition I have added the following endpoint from code to enable WS-Discovery:

```
var discoveryBehavior = new ServiceDiscoveryBehavior();
discoveryBehavior.AnnouncementEndpoints.Add(new UdpAnnouncementEndpoint());
serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(discoveryBehavior);
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint());
```

Now, from the local machine discovery and connection works just fine. I'm also able to connect to the service as expected using the wcftestclient and entering the url `http://192.168.0.16:8080` or `http://localhost:8080`. So so far so good.

Then i move my client to another machine and starts it.

The discovery works just fine, and it returns the url of the endpoint on the server machine, but when trying to connect it says that the endpoint is not found.

Also, inside the wcftestclient. i can't connect, and i trid both `http://192.168.0.16:8080` and `http://192.168.0.16:8080/AnchorService`.

So it seems that the discovery endpoint works from a remote machine, but not the service endpoint?

Any idea where I went wrong here?

Comment: Try by simplifying things, specify the full address of the endpoint in the config. Also specify the url of the mex endpoint in config.

Comment: Taking a guess here, but I'm thinking the UDP bit works on your LAN, but port 8080 is not firewalled for access from other machines. Try poking a hole in your service host's firewall at that port for machines on your LAN, and see if that helps.

Comment: @Jeroen - I though the same, but i tried to disable the entire firewall just to check if it worked, but no difference.

Comment: It ended up being a combination of firewall and wrong configuration. When I turned of the firewall the configuration was wrong so it didn't work, and when the configuration was correct I had turned the firewall back on.  **ashamed**

Comment: Don't worry, happens to all of us! Be sure to post an answer and accept it so future visitors with the same problem can easily spot your solution!